# How is the cost for Azure Function proxy calculated?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, price, azure-function-app-proxy

We have lots of images in Azure Blob Storage (LRS Hot). We calculate around 15 million downloads per month for a total of 5000 GB egress (files are on average 350kB). I can calculate the price for the Blob Storage but the Function proxy is unknown. The [Azure Functions pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/) document doesn't say anything about proxy functions and specifically about bandwidth.

**Question 1**: Are these calculations correct?

*Execution count price* is €0,169 per million executions, which equals to 15 * 0,169€=2,54€/month.

*GB-s price* is €0,000014/GB-s and memory usage is rounded to nearest 128MB. If file download time is 0,2s and memory is 128MB we have 0,2 * (128/1024) * 15000000 * 0,000014 = 5,25€/month

**Question 2**: What about bandwidth? Is there any cost for that?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Mostly yes.

Azure Functions Proxies (Preview) works just like regular functions, meaning that any routing done by your proxy counts as one execution. Also, just like standard functions, it uses your GB-s while it's running. Your calculation approach is correct, with the caveat that reading from blog storage is actually a streaming activity, which will consume a fixed amount of memory multipled by the time it will take to each file to download.

Q2: This works the same way as Azure App Service. From the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/?v=17.23h):

165 MB outbound network traffic included, additional outbound network bandwidth charged separately.

Comment: If bandwidth is billable we will then have an additional cost of 0,074€ * 5000 = 370€ which will then be quite a pricey proxy. Akamai cdn will be only 150€ more expensive.